# Jenkins nginx config 'not secure' two subdomains

Tags: nginx, domain, jenkins

I am getting a `not secure` on the website and I can't figure out why, here's the nginx config;

```
upstream jenkins-av-server {
  server jenkins.audience-view:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name audience-view.jenkins.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
       listen       443;
       server_name  audience-view.jenkins.example.com;

       ssl                  on;
       ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/certificates/example.com.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/certificates/example.com.key;

       ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

       ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:128m;
       ssl_session_timeout 10m;

       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

       access_log      /var/log/nginx/audience-view.jenkins.access.log;
       error_log       /var/log/nginx/audience-view.jenkins.error.log;

  location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_pass          http://jenkins.audience-view:8080;
       proxy_redirect http://jenkins.audience-view:8080 https://audience-view.jenkins.example.com;

       }
                                                                                                                                                                      1,12          Top
    }
```

Comment: Are you using self signed certificate?

Comment: No I'm not. I think it's a the 2 subdomains that's causing the error. As the warning disappears when change the `.jenkins` to `-jenkins`. the problem is I then get a `404 error`

Comment: Can you give more detail? What, exactly, is saying "not secure"? Is it Jenkins itself or is it your web browser?  If it's Jenkins, then you likely need to set the `JENKINS_URL` in your Jenkins configuration.  If it's your web browser, then you've likely incorrectly installed your SSL certificate or are using a certificate with an incorrect name or with an incorrect signature chain.

Comment: It's the web browser. On the left hand side by the URL